# Uncertainty with refactoring function with multiple parameters -- Am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am new to Ramda.js. I've been reading/learning a lot about the library lately, and am starting to apply my knowledge to "real life" code. One thing I am struggling w/ is refactoring functions with multiple parameters. I have something that works, but I'm not certain that this is the "best" way to do it. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

So here are my input arguments:

```
const normalizedData = [
    [-500, -500, -500, 0],
    [-400, -500, -400, 0],
    [-300, -500, -300, 0],
    [-200, -500, -200, 0],
    // ...
];

const is2D           = {
    x : false,
    y : false,
    z : true
};

const minHeight = 4;
```

The original function takes a 2D array of data and applies some transformation logic while flattening, but it requires 2 other parameters besides the data (minHeight, is2D). The output is fed to some WebGL code to render some 3D stuff.

This is my original function:

```
function computeTranslations_OLD(minHeight, is2D, normalizedData){
    return normalizedData.flatMap(el => {
        const [x, y1, y2, z] = el,
              yMin           = Math.min(y1, y2),
              height         = Math.max(Math.abs(y1 - y2), minHeight),
              yOrigin        = (height / 2) + yMin;

        return [
            is2D.x ? x + 2 : x, // x origin
            yOrigin,            // y origin
            is2D.z ? z + 2 : z, // z origin
            height
        ]
    });
}
```

And these are my refactored functions, basically split into a function that operates on each iteration, and a HOF that 'glues' it all together:

```
function computeTranslation(minHeight, is2D, normalizedData){
    const [x, y1, y2, z] = normalizedData,
          yMin           = Math.min(y1, y2),
          height         = Math.max(Math.abs(y1 - y2), minHeight),
          yOrigin        = (height / 2) + yMin;

    return [
        is2D.x ? x + 2 : x,
        yOrigin,
        is2D.z ? z + 2 : z,
        height
    ]
}

// HOF
function computeTranslations(minHeight, is2D, normalizedData){
    return R.chain(
        R.partial(
            computeTranslation,
            [minHeight, is2D]
        ),
        normalizedData
    );
}
```

Is this an acceptable approach for refactoring something like this? Or is there a better way? As is, it works, but being new to Ramda, and still wrapping my head around FP techniques... it would be nice to have some outside input.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're right to question this.  It feels awkward.

A first question, though, is *why* you want to use a Ramda implementation.  The code seems clean and understandable as is.  I'm a founder of Ramda and a big fan, but I treat it as a tool to use when it offers benefits, and to ignore otherwise.  It this is a learning exercise, that's fine.  But if not, they first question should probably not be *how do I do this in Ramda?* but *would Ramda tools improve this?*

Assuming you still want to use Ramda, then we can definitely improve the outer function.  And the first step would be to curry the inner one:

```js
const computeTranslation = R.curry(function(minHeight, is2D, normalizedData) {
    const [x, y1, y2, z] = normalizedData,
          yMin           = Math.min(y1, y2),
          height         = Math.max(Math.abs(y1 - y2), minHeight),
          yOrigin        = (height / 2) + yMin;

    return [
        is2D.x ? x + 2 : x,
        yOrigin,
        is2D.z ? z + 2 : z,
        height
    ]
})
```

Now all these are equivalent:

```js
/* 1 */ computeTranslation (minHeight, is2D, el)
/* 2 */ computeTranslation (minHeight, is2D) (el)
/* 3 */ computeTranslation (minHeight) (is2D, el)
/* 4 */ computeTranslation (minHeight) (is2D) (el)
```

And we can use that to write a cleaner version of `computeTranslations` (and here I switch to arrow functions as they are almost always neater.)

```js
const computeTranslations = (minHeight, is2D, normalizedData) => 
  R.chain (computeTranslation (minHeight, is2D)) (normalizedData)

computeTranslations (minHeight, is2D, normalizedData)
```

If you don't mind switching calling conventions a bit, then this can become slightly nicer:

```js
const computeTranslations = (minHeight, is2D) => 
  R.chain (computeTranslation (minHeight, is2D))

computeTranslations (minHeight, is2D) (normalizedData)
```

But we can go one step further and turn that into

```js
const computeTranslations = R.compose (R.chain, computeTranslation)

computeTranslations (minHeight, is2D) (normalizedData)
```

Currying is a very important feature of Ramda, and if it's not clear to you, I would suggest you investigate it further.  It is in good part what makes the typical Ramda style possible.  An [old article of mine](https://fr.umio.us/favoring-curry/) gives a pretty good introduction, and links to other useful sources.